# No Unity or Hud

Tags: unity, 13.04, software-updater

So i installed Ubuntu 13.04 and everything was working just fine. I installed my drivers for my Radeon HD 7770 restarted the computer and everything still worked fine but when i updated the software via the software updater and restarted unity was gone. It boots up to my desktop wallpaper with the folders on the desktop but the side panel and top panel are gone. I dont know what to do.

Comment: What got updated for software?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Unity

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --fix-broken --autoremove --yes unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-* unity-scope-* unity-webapps-* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt* overlay-scrollbar* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration
```